# I want to delete comments by a post in facebook graph API

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

when I generate with post `({app_id}_{post_id})`, I believed that delete for `/links` is  not supporting. But delete for `'/feed with link field or not is not supporting.POST delete properly but I want to delete comments by a post in facebook graph API.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if isn't supported POST use GET ajax doesn't need to open windows under a loop to take the GET values by the URL. And for the Delete comment you got an API for that :

```
/* PHP SDK v5.0.0 */
/* make the API call */
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'DELETE',
  '/{comment-id}'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
/* handle the result */
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/comment/